# HTML/CSS Across Various Screen Resolutions

Tags: html, css, web, screen, resolution

I've been working on my first practice website in HTML and CSS and using pixels and percentages, making the page look all nice on my screen. 
I took it to another computer with a much larger screen and nothing seemed to be in the same order or placement as what I had coded for my screen.

Is there a simple fix for this (to make it look the same no matter which browser, screen size, screen resolution etc. is being used)? At one point I tried changing all of the pixel values to percentages but the page got further disorganized.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post some of the code you need help with?

Comment: This question is pretty broad will likely be closed. You need to learn the basics of `CSS` (floats, inline vs block, etc.) and what is known as `Responsive Web Design`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to adjust your css to use percentages on a basic website, if you want to keep the size consistent across multiple monitor sizes.  Something along the lines of:

`width:20%`

You may also want look into Google's Canary web-browser to easily change the size and resolution of your browser for testing purposes.  [Google Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html)

Comment: Thanks! Google Canary's features are very useful.